# Can't get the code to work for this random number generator in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Everytime I click the button, it puts the new number but it won't get rid of the old one.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("random number generator")

def new_number():
  destroy()
  text = tk.Label(root, text=(random.randint(0,100)))
  text.pack(padx=0, pady=1)

def destroy():
  text.destroy()

text = tk.Label(root, text=(random.randint(0,100)))
text.pack(padx=0, pady=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text='new number', width=25, command=new_number)
button.pack(padx=1, pady=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("random number generator")

def new_number():
  text.config(text=random.randint(0, 100))

text = tk.Label(root, text=random.randint(0, 100))
text.pack(padx=0, pady=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text="New number", width=25, command=new_number)
button.pack(padx=1, pady=1)

root.mainloop()
```

It uses `<tkinter.Label>.config(text=<new text>)` to change the text inside the label. That runs faster thank your code. Also in your `new_number` function `text` is set to a new `<tkinter.Label>` but it isn't a global variable so it is causing you problems.